# How to disable Keycloak security for a particular API gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a **Restaurant** service. It exposes two endpoints (**`/v1/restaurant/order`, `/v1/restaurant/personalInfo`**). Some requests will be coming through API gateways and some will be coming directly to our service. For security I am using **Keycloak**.

Now my requirement is to disable the Keycloak security if the request is coming from some list of known API gateways (e.g *`http://api.gateway1.com/v1/restaurant/order`, `http://api.gateway2.com/v1/restaurant/personalInfo`*) otherwise enable it.

To enable or disable security I am maintaining list of IP addresses of API Gateways in my codebase.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
        .addFilterBefore(exceptionHandlerFilter(), KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.class);
    http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/version", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasIpAddress('192.160.53.80') or hasIpAddress('192.160.53.85')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

This solution works fine but if later in the future IP addresses will change then I need to make the code change and do deployment. I googled a lot but didn't find any solution.